# Is Sobolev space $H^{1}[0,1]$ closed w.r.t. $L^{2}$ norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Just wondering if $H^{1}[0,1]$ is a closed subset of $L^{2}[0,1]$. Thanks.

Comment: Since it contains smooth functions, it is dense in $L^ 2$, so its closure is $L^ 2$.

Comment: @D.Thomine what is wrong with the following argument? Say $f_k \to f$ in $L^2$ and take $k$ large so that $1 \ge ||f-f_k||_2^2 = \sum_n |\hat{f}(n)-\hat{f_k}(n)|^2$. Then by triangle inequality, we easily see $\sum_n |\hat{f}(n)|^2$ is finite

Comment: @mathworker21: ... and then?

Comment: @D.Thomine  Doesn't that mean $f \in H^1$?

Comment: @mathworker21: $\sum_n |\hat{f} (n)|^2 <+\infty$ just means it is in $L^2$.

Comment: @D.Thomine Of course. my apologies

Comment: @D.Thomine Thanks for your comment! So the closure will then include functions that do not have a continuous representative right? Does this further imply that any closed subset of $L^{2}$ necessarily contains functions that do not have a continuous representative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C_{0}^{\infty}(0,1)\subset H^1(0,1) \subset L^2(0,1) \Rightarrow L^2(0,1)=\overline{C_{0}^{\infty}(0,1)}^{\|\cdot\|_{L^2}}\subset \overline{H^1(0,1)}^{\|\cdot\|_{L^2}} \subset L^2(0,1) \Rightarrow \overline{H^1(0,1)}^{\|\cdot\|_{L^2}} = L^2(0,1)\neq H^1(0,1)$

Comment: Thanks a lot Victor! It's clear to me now. So this implies any closed subset in $L^{2}$ necessarily contains functions that do not have a continuous representative, right?